# How to use awk insert "." to string in the first column?

Tags: awk, sh

I have a file that contain some data.
How to use awk insert `.` to string in the first column?

Input file

```
MAC Address Inventory
MAC Address,IP Address
001a6b406ce8,172.18.1.1
001a6b50abdd,192.168.80.4
001a6b50f5e3,10.122.110.68
Total 3
```

Output file

```
MAC Address Inventory
MAC Address,IP Address
001a.6b40.6ce8,172.18.1.1
001a.6b50.abdd,192.168.80.4
001a.6b50.f5e3,10.122.110.68
Total 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it with `awk`

```
awk 'gsub(/\./,".")==3 {$0=substr($0,1,4)"."substr($0,5,4)"."substr($0,9)}1' file
MAC Address Inventory
MAC Address,IP Address
001a.6b40.6ce8,172.18.1.1
001a.6b50.abdd,192.168.80.4
001a.6b50.f5e3,10.122.110.68
Total 3
```

```
awk -F\. 'NF==4 {$0=substr($0,1,4)"."substr($0,5,4)"."substr($0,9)}1' OFS=\. file
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that you asked for `awk` but this is a natural for `sed`:

```
$ sed -r '/^[0-9a-f]+,/ s/^(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})/\1.\2.\3/g' infile
MAC Address Inventory
MAC Address,IP Address
001a.6b40.6ce8,172.18.1.1
001a.6b50.abdd,192.168.80.4
001a.6b50.f5e3,10.122.110.68
Total 3
```

From your example, it appears that you only want to do the period insertion if the first column contains a 12-digit hex number.  So, the expression `/^[0-9a-f]{12},/` tells `sed` to perform the substitution only on lines whose first column is such a hex number.  The substitution then grabs each the three groups of four and places a period between the groups.

Under OSX or other non-GNU system, replace `sed -r` with `sed -E`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]{4}/, "\&.", $0)
       sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]{4}\.[[:xdigit:]]{4}/, "\&.", $0)
       print }' input.file
```

It works; there might be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: To use interval `{4}` in `awk` you need `gnu awk` `4.0` or higher.  If you have older version, use `awk --re-interval 'code'`

Comment: @Jotne: I actually tested it with BSD `awk` (20070501) on Mac OS X 10.9.2.  However, I also have `gawk` 3.1.7 on the machine, and it does not work with that — which I find curious (unexpected, at any rate).  GNU `awk` also complains about the backslash before the ampersand, but since it doesn't match anyway, it doesn't make much difference. Removing the backslash is more consistent with POSIX.